# How to make Android layout like this?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-listview, android-gridview

I would like to know how to make layout as show on the image below. Specifically, I am interested in these images.

As you can see there is 10 images, and they are part of the review, and they are not scrollable, because they are part of root layout which is scrollable.

How to load multiple images and then show it to user like this?

With GridView, ListView or there is some other way?

[image]

Comment: 3 up votes dot know why, any way can you able to tell what you have tried

Comment: I think you have to use "ListView" add this item goes under list header 1.text which is above the image 2.all images 3. like and comment count. try to load all review as list item.

Answer (score 0):

http://www.androidhive.info/2012/02/android-gridview-layout-tutorial/ use this link try this u will get what you want... if it is right accept my ans

ImageAdapter.java

```
   package com.example.androidhive;

   import android.content.Context;
   import android.view.View;
   import android.view.ViewGroup;
   import android.widget.BaseAdapter;
   import android.widget.GridView;
   import android.widget.ImageView;

  public class ImageAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
private Context mContext;

// Keep all Images in array
public Integer[] mThumbIds = {
        R.drawable.pic_1, R.drawable.pic_2,
        R.drawable.pic_3, R.drawable.pic_4,
        R.drawable.pic_5, R.drawable.pic_6,
        R.drawable.pic_7, R.drawable.pic_8,
        R.drawable.pic_9, R.drawable.pic_10,
        R.drawable.pic_11, R.drawable.pic_12,
        R.drawable.pic_13, R.drawable.pic_14,
        R.drawable.pic_15
};

// Constructor
public ImageAdapter(Context c){
    mContext = c;
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return mThumbIds.length;
}

@Override
public Object getItem(int position) {
    return mThumbIds[position];
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
    return 0;
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    ImageView imageView = new ImageView(mContext);
    imageView.setImageResource(mThumbIds[position]);
    imageView.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.CENTER_CROP);
    imageView.setLayoutParams(new GridView.LayoutParams(70, 70));
    return imageView;
}
```

}

Comment: This is a not a GridView.

Answer (score 0):

This is a [GridLayout](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/GridLayout.html).

```
<ScrollView>

    <LinearLayout>

        <TextView/>

        <GridLayout .. />

    </LinearLayout>

</ScrollView>
```

Comment: Is recommendation to use GridView inside ScrolView? Because both of them are scrollable?

Comment: No, don't embed views with the same scrolling direction. In my proposal I am talking about a GridLayout, not a GridView.

Comment: It's not recommended, @Zookey. But [GridLayout](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/GridLayout.html) is different from GridView. There is a [simple example here](http://www.techotopia.com/index.php/Working_with_the_Android_GridLayout_in_XML_Layout_Resources).

Comment: Is there way to dynamically load data to grid layout? Because I am sending request to server, and response can be different number of pictures. It may be just an image, two images or multiple images.